# Declaring variable in loop or before loop in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, for-loop

Should I declare the _mcContainer var before the loop or no? (performance increase?)

```
for(var i:uint = _startIndex; i <= _endIndex; ++i){    
    var _mcContainer:MovieClip = _mcParent["i_" + _position];
}
```

or

```
var _mcContainer:MovieClip;
for(var i:uint = _startIndex; i <= _endIndex; ++i){
    _mcContainer = _mcParent["i_" + _position];
}
```

?

Comment: second option is faster, have a look at this: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2007/05/01/some-actionscript-30-optimizations/

Comment: @george, which part of that page relates to this question? I'm having trouble finding anything.

Comment: @spender "We can also speed up the loop by storing the array’s length in a variable outside of the loop" before 'Constants from other classes'...u are right...not in plain sight

Comment: @george-profenza but array's length is different case cause there if you don't use a var to reference to the length each time your loop will call need to get the array length over and over again. But in my case I was wondering does it change something if I declare the variable and it's type before the loop so on looping it wouldn't declare new variable each time.

Comment: ok, I see...in your case, as @spender mentioned it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: I think anyways it's good style to declare them before the loop. It's the same variable which is reused each time you go through the loop. So it makes sense, semantically, to have it declared before the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not hard to test...

...however according to the docs, it shouldn't make any difference because variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the method block anyway.

From [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html):

> An interesting implication of the lack of block-level scope is that you can read or write to a variable before it is declared, as long as it is declared before the function ends. This is because of a technique called hoisting , which means that the compiler moves all variable declarations to the top of the function.

Comment: Good point. This has bitten me several times when I was developing in AS3. Other compilers like C++ (and even Java) recognize using a variable before it is declared as a compile-time error.

Comment: From the Flex coding conventions: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions#CodingConventions-Variables i thought that i've to declare variables only before they are used and that would increase performance, but thanks to your docs reference i see it does not. :] Thanks!

Comment: Having variables declared after they are used reduce code legibility, in my opinion. They should be declared before they are used - in worst case in the same line. But not later.